# Invert corners Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I'm trying to follow a tutorial. 
I'm trying to invert the corners of alternating rectangular bars that make up the lighter pink shape.
However, when I try to invert the corners with the live corners/direct selection step that most site recommend, I get a corner that IS inverted but has a point in the middle. 
That's not what I'm looking for. How do I acheive the corner inversions that are in the tutorial without having to individually adjust the points/paths of the corner?

TOP:My inverted corners
BOTTOM:Tutorial

[image: my inverted corners]

[image: tutorial inverted corners]

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial screenshot shows the separate bars United using Pathfinder. If you unite all of your bars together and then use Live Corners to adjust the corners as "round" corners (don't use "inverted round"), you'll end up with the effect shown in the tutorial.

If you are applying Unite, but still having a problem, it may be that some of your bars are not actually touching each other...so UNITE is not united them. What you are then doing is applying live corners to each bar as a separate objects. The pointy ends are the result of applying inverted round to the end of an individual object.